# Mongo DB - Aggregation Query Slowness

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

In mongo DB I am doing aggregation on table records to get average of total and count,

**Currently its taking more then 5 seconds to complete**

**Mongo DB Query** ||
**Table Contains more then 4 million records**

```
db.abc.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "source.type": "test",
        eventTime: {
            $gte: ISODate("2021-12-19T18:30:00.000Z")
        },
        storeId: {
            "$in": [ObjectId("60da3367e2436d3c043c0289"), ObjectId("60da3469e2436d3c043c0452"),
            ObjectId("5fb2e7fe805d142ba80eb9cd"), ObjectId("60afdc1bdacb761a4c9a3a0a"),
            ObjectId("60afe00edacb761a4c9a3d4a"), ObjectId("6083134746b0331eccde72e9"),
            ObjectId("60ae5aebb8476c1cd02e51f2"), ObjectId("5ffb243269d776101880aa2a"),
            ObjectId("60801f15da33b704a4169d9c"), ObjectId("6088b6ae2d43722100fec785"),
            ObjectId("60994e2be5b8121f3c57a347"), ObjectId("609ec903047f9e1810acbc9a"),
            ObjectId("60a282cb047f9e1810afd798"), ObjectId("60df736ee5371d5424021e00"),
            ObjectId("60ef90be05c8f640cce8afa8"), ObjectId("60f1cc123d9dcf48ac0c8d0a"),
            ObjectId("60a46919a3fd8238f065e32e"), ObjectId("5e32613b241a472a6c0c99b9"),
            ObjectId("612cee002a122903b87c7627"), ObjectId("60898cf7e5b8121f3c50e613"),
            ObjectId("60a195df047f9e1810af1693"), ObjectId("60a196ab047f9e1810af1774"),
            ObjectId("60a282cd047f9e1810afd79a"), ObjectId("60c3c312a3dec91cbc23526c"),
            ObjectId("60ca867628872b1d34580cf5"), ObjectId("60d276deee09a13244438ef8"),
            ObjectId("60d42f165e41bc32d847c6be"), ObjectId("60d42f1d5e41bc32d847c6c7"),
            ObjectId("60d42f235e41bc32d847c6d0"), ObjectId("60d42f235e41bc32d847c6d1"),
            ObjectId("60d42f2c5e41bc32d847c6da"), ObjectId("60d42f315e41bc32d847c6e9"),
            ObjectId("60d42f495e41bc32d847c70b"), ObjectId("60d42f505e41bc32d847c714"),
            ObjectId("60d42f555e41bc32d847c719"), ObjectId("60d42fcf5e41bc32d847c811"),
            ObjectId("60d51ca15e41bc32d84954e3"), ObjectId("60d51cd65e41bc32d8495552"),
            ObjectId("60d51ddf5e41bc32d84956be"), ObjectId("60d51dfb5e41bc32d84956fb"),
            ObjectId("60d51e025e41bc32d849570f"), ObjectId("60d51e045e41bc32d8495719"),
            ObjectId("60d51e0a5e41bc32d8495730"), ObjectId("60d51e165e41bc32d8495753"),
            ObjectId("60d51e285e41bc32d849576c"), ObjectId("60d51e315e41bc32d8495773"),
            ObjectId("60d536b35e41bc32d8497af3"), ObjectId("60d537f55e41bc32d8497ca8"),
            ObjectId("60d538025e41bc32d8497cb5"), ObjectId("60d538055e41bc32d8497cb8"),
            ObjectId("60d538065e41bc32d8497cb9"), ObjectId("60d538095e41bc32d8497cbe"),
            ObjectId("60d538145e41bc32d8497cc9"), ObjectId("60d538165e41bc32d8497ccc"), ObjectId("60d538315e41bc32d8497ce6"),
            ObjectId("60d538335e41bc32d8497ce9"), ObjectId("60d5383c5e41bc32d8497cf6"), ObjectId("60d538645e41bc32d8497d17"),
            ObjectId("60d538685e41bc32d8497d1e"), ObjectId("60d538815e41bc32d8497d3f"), ObjectId("60d5388c5e41bc32d8497d56"),
            ObjectId("60d5389c5e41bc32d8497d71"), ObjectId("60d538a35e41bc32d8497d7e"), ObjectId("60d5419a5e41bc32d8498a8b"),
            ObjectId("60d562915e41bc32d849ba05"), ObjectId("60d562b25e41bc32d849ba34"), ObjectId("60d588c45e41bc32d849f198"),
            ObjectId("60d71ad6e2436d3c0436c09f"), ObjectId("60d9f847e2436d3c043ba3a5"), ObjectId("60ff57692ffad505a88db8a2"), ObjectId("610267968db91b2f507f3a53"),
            ObjectId("61035ae58db91b2f50812008"), ObjectId("61035ae58db91b2f5081200d"), ObjectId("61035c678db91b2f50812303"), ObjectId("61035cc18db91b2f508123c2"),
            ObjectId("61035cc38db91b2f508123ca"), ObjectId("6109713caf4cf95bf015817e"), ObjectId("610c08dd76111d38289bee0d"), ObjectId("610c28bb76111d38289c3c37"),
            ObjectId("610c48ec76111d38289c9298"), ObjectId("610c506a76111d38289ca7f4"), ObjectId("610c599876111d38289cc2c2"), ObjectId("610c64d276111d38289ce23c"),
            ObjectId("61135a7c7e022f46607b79e1"), ObjectId("61135c7f7e022f46607b8037"), ObjectId("611364a07e022f46607b9840"), ObjectId("611365cf7e022f46607b9be3"),
            ObjectId("6113685f7e022f46607ba36d"), ObjectId("6113692d7e022f46607ba5d2"), ObjectId("61139ad47e022f46607c3d83"), ObjectId("61139bda7e022f46607c40d5"),
            ObjectId("61139d427e022f46607c44f3"), ObjectId("61139e287e022f46607c47fa"), ObjectId("61139f207e022f46607c4b00"), ObjectId("6113a3517e022f46607c57e3"),
            ObjectId("6113a8c27e022f46607c68b4"), ObjectId("6113af647e022f46607c7d1c"), ObjectId("6113b37b7e022f46607c88e8"), ObjectId("61146b407e022f46607ee092"),
            ObjectId("61146c9a7e022f46607ee426"), ObjectId("61146dba7e022f46607ee7a1"), ObjectId("611476657e022f46607f0610"), ObjectId("61147a1d7e022f46607f139f"),
            ObjectId("61147b797e022f46607f1848"), ObjectId("611480477e022f46607f2868"), ObjectId("611480d97e022f46607f2a26"), ObjectId("611480da7e022f46607f2a28"),
            ObjectId("611480e27e022f46607f2a4a"), ObjectId("6114818f7e022f46607f2cbb"), ObjectId("6114ba167e022f46607fee30"), ObjectId("6114ba187e022f46607fee3a"),
            ObjectId("6114ba187e022f46607fee3b"), ObjectId("6114ba1d7e022f46607fee4c"), ObjectId("6114ba207e022f46607fee53"), ObjectId("6114ba207e022f46607fee54"),
            ObjectId("6114ba227e022f46607fee5d"), ObjectId("6114d5af7e022f4660804c3a"), ObjectId("6114d5b27e022f4660804c47"), ObjectId("6114d5b57e022f4660804c4f"),
            ObjectId("6114d5b77e022f4660804c57"), ObjectId("6114d5b77e022f4660804c58"), ObjectId("6114d5b77e022f4660804c59"), ObjectId("6114d5c37e022f4660804c89"), ObjectId("6114d5c77e022f4660804c94"),
            ObjectId("6115f1d67e022f4660844e69"), ObjectId("6115feda7e022f466084839e"), ObjectId("6115fedf7e022f46608483bc"), ObjectId("6115fee37e022f46608483c9"), ObjectId("6115fee57e022f46608483d6"),
            ObjectId("6115fee67e022f46608483dc"), ObjectId("6115fee77e022f46608483e0"), ObjectId("6115fee77e022f46608483e1"), ObjectId("6115feea7e022f46608483ef"), ObjectId("611610e17e022f466084cdbc"),
            ObjectId("611610e27e022f466084cdc0"), ObjectId("611610e27e022f466084cdc7"),
            ObjectId("611610f87e022f466084ce21"), ObjectId("611b3ec32747fc3e840522eb"), ObjectId("611b3ed72747fc3e84052356"),
            ObjectId("611b3ed82747fc3e8405235a"), ObjectId("611b3ee02747fc3e84052386"),
            ObjectId("611b3ee62747fc3e840523a7"), ObjectId("611b46aa2747fc3e84054d8c"), ObjectId("611b57352747fc3e8405a993"),
            ObjectId("611b573b2747fc3e8405a9ad"), ObjectId("611ed06850295574f871999e"), ObjectId("61241b6bdd388470f4e9c086"),
            ObjectId("609414e6e5b8121f3c555cf0"), ObjectId("6114ba187e022f46607fee39")]
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: { "_id": null, avg: { $avg: "$total" }, count: { $count: {} } }
}],{ allowDiskUse: true})
```

**Output of Query**
`[ { "_id": null, "avg": 7.114596403409916, "count": 433911 } ]`

**Server Configurations**

1. 64 GB Memory
2. NVME Hard Drive
3. Mongo 5.0.1
4. Database Size around 9 GB

**Explain Result -**https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u3BqQu1G5Mr4G0JVJSFgusWQeBMfkzUu/view?usp=sharing

**Current indexes present on collection**

1. "eventTime": -1, "source.type": -1, "storeId": -1, "total": -1
2. "_id" : -1
3. "storeId" :-1
4. "eventTime" : -1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.